# mysql select total which don't exist

Tags: php, mysql

I am try to get a count of all missing translations and getting really lost in how to do it.

Tables:

- languages (language_id, name)
- products (product_id)
- product_translations (product_id, language_id, name)

The admin are getting very lazy and I want to be able to show them a count of how many translations are missing.

I guess a very simple was of doing this would be to just get the total (languages->count * products->count) but I wanted to return a count for each product separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do such a query, start with a `driver` table (subquery) that has all combinations.  Then remove the ones that have translations:

```
select driver.*
from (select distinct l.language_id, p.product_id
      from languages l cross join
           products p
     ) driver left outer join
     translations t
     on t.language_id = driver.language_id and
        t.product_id = driver.product_id
where t.language_id is null;
```

This uses a `left outer join`, which keeps everything in the `driver` table.  If there is no match, then the columns in `translations` will be `NULL` -- the `where` clause keeps only these.

The `distinct` may not be necessary in the subquery, if the values in each table are unique.

As a note:  the above is my preferred way to write the query, because I think it is the clearest in intent.  But, MySQL actually materializes the subquery.  So the following is more efficient, if the columns are unique in the two reference tables:

```
select l.*, p.*
from languages l cross join
     products p left outer join
     translations t
     on t.language_id = l.language_id and
        t.product_id = p.product_id
where t.language_id is null;
```